# "borrow of moved value" after calling Rust struct function

Tags: rust, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a Rust implementation of a binary search tree. I'm getting an error by calling one of the node's functions after printing the node's values:

```
#[derive(Default)]
//# [derive(Copy)]
pub struct Node {
    data: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
//option is used when the property could either be a type or None.
//if just `left: Node`, rust will panic because `recursive without indirection`

//impl Copy for Node { }

// impl Clone for Node {
//  fn clone(&self) -> Node {
//      *self
//  }
// }

impl Node {
    fn print_data(&self) -> i32 {
        self.data
    }

    fn default() -> Node {
        //function to help when instantiate node with no children
        Node {
            data: 0,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }

    fn set_left(&mut self, new_left: Option<Box<Node>>) -> () {
        self.left = new_left
    }
    fn set_right(&mut self, new_right: Option<Box<Node>>) -> () {
        self.right = new_right
    }

    fn swap_childs(&mut self) -> () {
        std::mem::swap(&mut self.left, &mut self.right);
    }
}

fn get_data(a_node: &Node) -> i32 {
    a_node.data
}

fn main() {
    let node4 = Node {
        data: 4,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let mut node3 = Node {
        data: -3,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    node3.set_left(Some(Box::new(node4)));

    let node5 = Node {
        data: 5,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    node3.set_right(Some(Box::new(node5)));

    // We have a tree!?
    println!("node3 val is {}", get_data(&node3));

    let left = get_data(&node3.left.unwrap());
    println!("node3 left val is {}", left);

    let right = get_data(&node3.right.unwrap());
    println!("node3 right val is {}", right);

    node3.swap_childs(); //causes error
}
```

Here's my error

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `node3`
  --> src/main.rs:76:5
   |
73 |     let right = get_data(&node3.right.unwrap());
   |                           ----------- value moved here
...
76 |     node3.swap_childs(); //causes error
   |     ^^^^^ value borrowed here after partial move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `node3.right` has type `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<Node>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I'm aware that the reason for this error is because my struct can't implement the `Copy` trait (because of `Box`?) (see commented out `Copy` and `Clone` implementation). I thought the `get_data` function / `mut` declaration would help. How can I solve this?

Comment: The [duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=430056d2d498219e5e5f5353181a2706).

Comment: thank you @Shepmaster . is there a difference between the & and as_ref()? are they not both references?

Comment: Yes, there's a difference between `&Option<T>` and `Option<&T>`.